# Post install is replacing npm install folder in linux

Tags: linux, npm, npm-install, post-install

I am doing npm install ,after that it is creating node modules folder .
then there is post install option is there which is working fine in windows but in Linux box it is deleting node modules and creating again .

**package.json format:**

```
{
  "someDependency":{
    "@fortawesome/ember-fontawesome": "0.1.9",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "5.1.0",
  },
  "scripts":{
    "postInstall": "npm install --abc download"
  }
}
```

can anyone help me with how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Is this in your root package.json or one of your dependencies?

Comment: root package.json

Comment: Try this -> "npm install --abc download" save this in a xyz.js file, make it executable and then  edit this line postInstall": "path/to/xyz.js"